# How we can find the level of a node in a tree using kalnoy/nestedset package | Laravel | nestedset

Tags: php, laravel, nested-sets

I am working on a Laravel application where I used [kalnoy/nestedset](https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset) package to make the tree structure for color categories. Now I want to know the level of the node related to the tree.

For example

```
Colors
    Red
        Dark red
            very dark red
        Light red
    Green
        Dark Green
    Blue
        Dark Blue
```

In my above context, I have the main three colors. So the main colors have level 1 and children of those have level 2 and so on.

Now the problem is how can we get the level of a node from the node instance

```
$color = Color::find(12); // let says it is "very dark red color"

echo "Get level of the above color";
```

***Why***

Because I actually allow the user to add custom colors if not present in the system. But I don't want to allow the end-user to create color for level 4. So a user can create up to 3 levels of colors.

So in my above case if someone sends me the "Very dark red" color instance as a parent whose level is 3 then further no more children should be created from this parent.

Comment: Just throwing some ideas out, since it seems possible (from scanning the repo briefly) to get the ancestors of a node, you could track back up the tree to the root to calculate depth of your node. Also depending on how accessible, you could perhaps augment the tree to store the depth of the nodes in a property.

Comment: difficult to understand. if possible please provide some code.